# How to open a program from a text file in Python

Tags: python, file

How would I go about opening a file in Python by referring to a text file. EXAMPLE:

```
    f.open('openthis.txt')
```

Then I would have openthis.txt in the same folder that would say:

> C:\Folder\myprogram.exe

Therefore the code opens up myprogram.exe from the directory

I want to do this so the code is easily changable, instead of having to edit it in IDLE every time I want to change the file I open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Specifically, you'd do something like:

```
import subprocess

with open("inputfile", "rb") as f:
    subprocess.call(f.read())
```

Comment: Would I need an 'import subprocess' or something along those lines?

Comment: yup, I'll edit the code to make that clear for future readers

Comment: @Kyle: not sure about the "rb"... isn't 'inputfile' the _text_ file containing the name of the executable? so why use binary mode?

Comment: @isedev: probably not necessary, just habit on my part :)